# Call to undefined session_set_cookie_params()

Tags: php, apache

I want use php function "session_set_cookie_params()", but it isn't work.
Here is source code.

```
$ cat test.php
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
  session_set_cookie_params(0, '/dir/');
?>

$ php -v
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Jul  5 2013 00:19:53)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies

$ php test.php
Fatal error: Call to undefined function session_set_cookie_params() in / (...) /dir/test.php on line 3
```

(On web browser, same output.)

I think php config file (/usr/local/etc/php.conf) have a problem, but it is seem to don't have problem. (It is default.)

Could you tell me answer this question ?

Comment: It is likely that function has been disabled for security reasons. Check the value of `disable_functions` in your `php.ini`

Comment: I checked my php.ini , so I discovered "disable_functions", I config 'disable_functions = "Off"', after apache restart, I checked "disable_function = Off" on phpinfo(); , but printed same error.

Comment: This question solved myself. I did install 'www/p5-HTTP-Cookies' and 'lang/php5-extensions', after executived same code, work this (I guess www/p5-HTTP_Cookies?).

Comment: :O didn't expected this.